# How can I get the Lists inside an Object? c#

Tags: c#, list, object, ienumerable, getproperty

I have this `object`:

```
Object
 Adress - count = 2 - System.Collections.Generic.List<Address>
  [0]   Address
    City - "Text" - string
    State - "Text" - string
  [1]   Address
    City - "Text" - string
    State - "Text" -string
 Notes - "Text" - string
 Items - Type(Item)
  Item - count = 2 - System.Collections.Generic.List<Item>
   [0]  Item
    Name - "Text" - string
    Price - "Text" - string
   [1]  Item
    Name - "Text" - string
    Price - "Text" - string
```

In this object, Address is a list of all addresses, notes is just another field of the object and items has a child named item and it contains Lists inside, just like address.

I am getting the value of notes by this code:

```
foreach (var item in (object as IEnumerable).Cast<object>().ToList())
                    {
    String substring = item.GetType().GetProperty("Notes").GetValue(item).ToString();
}
```

This is the return I get from the method when it passes to List:`System.Collections.Generic.List1[Address]`

But I can't access the lists, I need to separate this object in X Lists, like this:

```
Object2
 Adress
  [0]
  [1]

Object3
 Items
  Item
   [0]
   [1]
```

And then I can get the values using the method above, any suggestions? I already tried so many ways...

Comment: It would be awesome if you could create a [mcve].

Comment: I need to get the values from the lists inside of the object, i can't get that, i'm just getting the values from notes (that is not a List)

Comment: My `foreach` just return to me the notes values, when it passes the adress, i return : System.Collections.Generic.List1[Address]

Comment: I think at least you just need to give a source of your Object to us, so we may help you.

Comment: My object is created in another part of the program and it has that structure that i write on the question, how can i explain better? (i'm new at stack)

Comment: @LucioZenir Take a look at the link that mjwills provided. Then ask yourself, "Is my question minimal?", "Is my question complete?", "Is my question Verifiable?". Look at your question as is and see if you can reproduce what is happening based solely on what you put in the question. I can tell you that at the very least you haven't shown us the types of any of the objects/fields/properties in your question. The question should be reproducible by anyone who reads it. Try to make some edits following the guidelines from the link that mjwills provided.

Answer (score 2):

Just cast the value of Adress property to `List<Object>`, like this

```
foreach (var item in (object as IEnumerable).Cast<object>().ToList())
{
    List<Object> address = item.GetType().GetProperty("Adress").GetValue(item) as List<Object>;
    foreach(var ad in address)
    {
        //do what you want here
    }
}
```

Comment: List<Object> address = item.GetType().GetProperty("Address").GetValue(item) as List<Object>;

this get's null. any clue why?

Comment: That is because Address property is not a list, inspect it, like this  `item.GetType().GetProperty("Address").GetValue(item).GetType()`. Maybe is a IEnumerable<Object> and not a List<Object>. You must inspect the property.

Comment: -  item.GetType().GetProperty("Address").GetValue(item).GetType‌​() {Name = "List`1" FullName = "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Address, Address, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"} System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
it appears to be a list

Comment: Cast it then to List<Address> like this: `List<Address> address = item.GetType().GetProperty("Address").GetValue(item) as List<Address>;`

Comment: It still return null when i cast it to a List, maybe i'm doing something wrong

Comment: i just got it, i needed to use 2 casts so i can get the values from the lists, thanks for the tips